# How do I fix my Cucumber expectation error when polling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, long-polling

I have the helper `sign_in` which signs in a user. I'm trying to use a new approach to make sure that the user signed in using polling:

```
def sign_in(user, password = '111111')
  # ...
  click_button 'sign-in-btn'

  eventually(5){ page.should have_content user.username.upcase }
end
```

And here is `eventually`:

```
module AsyncSupport
  def eventually(timeout = 2)
    polling_interval = 0.1
    time_limit = Time.now + timeout

    loop do
      begin
        yield
        rescue Exception => error
      end
      return if error.nil?
      raise error if Time.now >= time_limit
      sleep polling_interval
    end
  end
end

World(AsyncSupport)
```

The problem is that some of my tests fail with an error:

```
expected to find text "USER_EMAIL_1" in "{\"success\":true,\"redirect_url\":\"/users/1/edit\"}" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/support/spec_helper.rb:25:in `block in sign_in'
./features/support/async_support.rb:8:in `block in eventually'
./features/support/async_support.rb:6:in `loop'
./features/support/async_support.rb:6:in `eventually'
./features/support/spec_helper.rb:23:in `sign_in'
./features/step_definitions/user.steps.rb:75:in `/^I am logged in as a "([^\"]*)"$/'
features/user/edit.feature:8:in `And I am logged in as a "user"'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/user/edit.feature:6 # Scenario: Editing personal data
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do any of that.

Capybara has [Powerful synchronization features mean you never have to manually wait for asynchronous processes to complete](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/)

Your test for `page.should have_content` just needs a bit more time, you can give it to it in the step or as a general setup.  The default wait is 2 seconds, and you might need 5 seconds or more.

Add `Capybara.default_wait_time = 5`

In the link above, search down and find **Asynchronous JavaScript (Ajax and friends)**

You should be able to delete your `AsyncSupport` entirely.  Just remember, if you set this inside a step and you want the wait to be 2 seconds otherwise, you might want an `ensure` block to set it back to the original time.

Comment: But this is changing the wait for every command - not just the one that's failing?

Comment: In that case you need to change it then restore the original after assertion. That is how we do it in most cases so we can keep the global wait lower.

Comment: This is what our tests do too. There should be a function to do this. I saw some code where a `wait: x` parameter had been used. But this doesn't appear to be standard...